# OpenCV 2.4.9 SimpleBlobDetector Debug Assertion Failed ..dbgdel.cpp line:52 _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

The error is like
Debug Assertion Failed!

File:f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\dbgdel.cpp

Line 52

Expression" _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead-> nBlockUse)

my code is like:

```
bool test()
{
Mat testImg = imread("test.bmp",0);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
SimpleBlobDetector::Params &parameters = SimpleBlobDetector::Params();
parameters.maxArea = 100000;
parameters.maxThreshold = 1000;
Ptr<FeatureDetector> Detector  =  new SimpleBlobDetector(parameters);
Detector->detect(testImg,keypoints);
return true;
}
```

I have tried to delete the Detector but didn't work, the error occurs in the last return sentense and my environment is Visual Studio 2015 32bit Debug mode,and opencv version is 2.4.9.

Beside, when I debug into it, the error appears when releasing the object in core/operation.hpp

```
~Ptr(){ release();}
```

When deleting the obj in line around 2616, it shows the error window.

--------------update------------

Thank user10605163 and molbdnilo. Sorry that I'm not so familiar with smart pointer so I delete it just to make sure there's no mistakes like memory leaks.

I change my code as follow:

```
Mat testImg = imread("testIMG.bmp",0);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
SimpleBlobDetector::Params parameters;
parameters.maxArea = 100000;
parameters.maxThreshold = 1000;
SimpleBlobDetector Detector(parameters);
Detector.detect(testImg,keypoints);
return true;
```

Still ,it doesn't work, but the error is a little different :

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
File:minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
Line:892
Expression:is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)
```

This time the error seems to occur when deconstructing the vector.
In include/vector around line 973:

```
~vector()
{
   _Tidy();
}
_Tidy()
{
 /* ... */
 this->_Getal().deallocate(this->_Myfitst(),this->Myend() - this->_Myfirst());
/*...*/

}
/*debugging into, at delete_scalar.cpp line 17 _free_dbg() */
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block,_UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

It's wierd that the error occurs when the vector is deconstructing, but if I comment `Detector.detect(testImg,keypoint)`,without changing other things about the vector,it works fine (but does not do anything though).And the wierdest thing is, when I test the origin code in OpenCV project that build from the source code(same version, VS 2015 32bit Debug too), it worked well!

-----------------update--------------------

Finally I built the opencv source code and use the lib file in my project, and it worked fine.Before I was using the lib extracted from the exe file.

Comment: `I have tried to delete the Detector`: What does this mean? Is the error shown from this exact code you posted? `Ptr` is a shared smart pointer, it should not be `delete`d. Why are you using `new` and the non-standard reference binding anyway? Just declare automatic storage duration non-reference variables: `SimpleBlobDetector::Params parameters;` and `SimpleBlobDetector Detector(parameters);`.

Comment: `parameters` is a non-const reference to a temporary object that doesn't exist after that line; using it is undefined and anything can happen. That it compiles is a known bug in Visual C++ (although Microsoft prefer to call it "language extension").

Comment: @user10605163 yes the code is show from that code, and after change to non-reference variables, it shows another error as shown in the update.

Comment: @user10605163 @molbdnilo thanks again. By initializing the vector with a (large enough) size (like 100), `vector<KeyPoint> keypoints(100);`it works well .(though I don't know why...)